# Synergy reports connected but mouse doesn't hop between screens

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, mouse, synergy

I'm using synergy between two windows computers (Windows 7 32-bit, acting as the server part, and Windows XP 32-bit, as a client).

I'm running the server part as admin, as suggested in some posts when running synergy in Vista/7, and I think it's properly configured in the server part:

[image]

It reports on both sides that the connection has succesfully been established, but there's no way to move the mouse from one screen to the other (neither from server2client, nor client2server).

Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing similar issues with a Linux 64 bit host (1.3.8) and a Windows 7 client (same version of Synergy) having tried both the 32 bit and 64 bit Windows versions. I will try out the beta version now on the client (this works with the Mac using 1.3.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem and I solved it by running the beta version of Synergy (1.4.4) on both systems.

I hope it helps

Comment: Great!! It worked! Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: I upgraded to the 1.4.5 beta on the Linux server, and Windows client. Everything seems to be working properly now, even the Mac client on the older version.